# Defeat all targets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script, but doesn't work, when i kill one enemy the door opens, i need to know how active the door when i kill all enemies. I need to destroy all enemies to open the door, but doesn't work good, if i kill one enemy the door opens for no reason.

```
public class DoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{     
    private GameObject[] enemyToKill;
 
    public Transform pos1, pos2;
    public float speed;
    public Transform startPos;
 
    Vector3 nextPos;
 
    public bool EnemyDead = false;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemyToKill = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyR1");
        nextPos = startPos.position;
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach (GameObject enemy in enemyToKill)
        {
            if (enemy == null)
            {                     
                EnemyDead = true;
                if (transform.position == pos1.position && EnemyDead)
                {
                    nextPos = pos2.position;
                }
 
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
 
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(pos1.position, pos2.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your code, I assume when a GameObject becomes null, that means the object is dead.  If that is the case, your code only checks for the first occurrence of a dead object. You need to change the foreach so that you check if ALL your objects are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are setting your bool to true for the first enemy that is killed.

You should rather check if **all** enemies are non existent. In general do **never** compare anything derived from `UnityEngine.Object` for `null`! Rather use the implicit `bool` operator.
Then you could use [Linq `Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) (or [`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all)) like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

void Update()
{
    // In general use a bool check!
    // A destroyed object reference is not necessarily null
    // This returns true if there is still an existing enemy
    if(!EnemyDead && enemyToKill.Anyy(enemy => enemy)) return;

    // Still keep the flag so the check can be skipped
    // As soon as the flag is already set
    EnemyDead = true;
                          
    if (transform.position == pos1.position)
    {
        nextPos = pos2.position;
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assume correctly (it is not clear from above code), You have set to all enemies some tag "EnemyR1" and now You want to check, if those enemies exists or not. If there are no enemies, you want to open the doors (like exit point for player).

It also depends, if you kill the enemy immediately (and destroy the GameObject), or you only mark enemy as something (set some property/set is non-active/set different tag).

In the code you want to:

```
void Start()
{
    // There you will get ALL objects that have the tag (that was ok before)
    // This function always returns Array. Sometimes empty.
    enemyToKill = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyR1");
    nextPos = startPos.position;
}
 
void Update()
{
    // Now it depends how your logic is implemented:
    // If you destroy automatically all objects, array will be empty, check length:
    if (enemyToKill.Length == 0)
    {
        //There are no enemies to be killed, You can open the door
    }

    // Else if objects still exist, you must check if all have the condition.
    // They can be disabled, have some property, etc.. In that case You need to:
    bool allKilled = true;
    foreach (GameObject enemy in enemyToKill)
    {
        if (enemy.active) //update this condition as you need
        {
            allKilled = false; // Set to false, when enemy is not killed
            break;             // and exit the loop
        }
    }
    if (allKilled)
    {
        //There are no enemies to be killed, You can open the door
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your answer and the door doesn't moves when the enemies is killed.

Comment: the line when you put  if (allKilled) is not activated when i kill all enemies, i check this when I put a bool inside and is always is false.

Comment: Thank you for respond, the problem it' solved correctly.